# Mustache iteration through numerically indexed array

Tags: php, mustache

I'm new to [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), and can't seem to find a way to do the following:

Data:

```
$errors = array('Error one', 'error two', 'error three');
```

Desired output:

```
Error one<br />error two<br />error three
```

I would achieve this using PHP:

```
<?=implode('<br />', $errors)?>
```

Tried to so far:

```
{{#errors}}{{.}}<br />{{/errors}}
```

Which translates to *an extra **br** at the end*, given Mustache is logicless I don't think it can cut out the last one, maybe something with counts?

Is it possible using Mustache? If so, how??

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Seems elaborate for something simple, I guess using Mustache also means designing your data to conform with the templating system...

Comment: See edit, although I've decided not to use Mustache — I'll leave the question up in case someone has an answer.

Comment: Mustache does not require you to change your data, but it does require you to keep your logic out of the template file. See this comment for an example of how to accomplish this sort of separation: http://hile.mn/VzbcOT

Comment: Ah yes thank you for the link, I'll have a go at abstracting the formatting with view models, looks exciting :)

Comment: Here's a fleshed out example that actually works: https://gist.github.com/61161639d8be82a75b5e